# Pandas: reset_index after pd.PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am having problem with resetting the index after I made the columns groupby and PeriodIndex.

[City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv](https://github.com/irJERAD/Intro-to-Data-Science-in-Python/blob/master/MyNotebooks/City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv)

```
housing = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv')
housing.drop(housing.columns[[0, 3, 4, 5]], axis=1, inplace=True)
housing.replace({'State': states}, inplace=True)
housing.set_index(['State', 'RegionName'], inplace=True)
housing.drop(housing.columns[housing.columns < '2000' ].tolist(), axis=1, inplace=True)
housing = housing.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(housing.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()
```

I had to make some multi-index so that I can make some frequency and change the rest of the columns, after I achieved that, I wanted to reset the index.

```
housing.reset_index()
```

This function doesn't return an error, however it does not make changes and the multi-index remained.

I also can't add some columns with the dataframe i.e.:

```
housing['new_column'] = None
```

But I want to reset all so I can manipulate somethings again.

Comment: "also can't add some columns" - what happens?

Comment: Hi I can't query a column. :( i.e. housing['2008Q3']

Comment: got me this error: pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)() KeyError: '2008Q3'

Comment: You have to provide an example of what you tried to do, what was the data, and what did not work. And since it is a different issue, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`housing.reset_index()` returns a copy of your dataframe. Either save this copy:

```
housing = housing.reset_index()
```

or request the modification in place:

```
housing.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Woah whaaaat!? It worked. I have been scratching. I thought it was the PeriodIndex.