# Pandas: Query after PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas

How to query a column after a groupby then PeriodIndex. This is a follow up to my first answered question.

[Link to the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687024/pandas-reset-index-after-pd-periodindex)

I cant query a column named after a Period. For example:

```
housing['2008Q3']
```

This is the error returned:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: '2008Q3'
```

What I learned: When I list my columns it returned:

```
['State',
 'RegionName',
 Period('2008Q3', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2008Q4', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2009Q1', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2009Q2', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2009Q3', 'Q-DEC'),
 Period('2009Q4', 'Q-DEC')]
```

I want to cancel the period and just make them string.
I tried

```
housing[Period('2009Q4', 'Q-DEC')]
```

but got me this error:

```
name 'Period' is not defined
```

Lol

Comment: Try `housing[pandas.Period('2009Q4', 'Q-DEC')]` or `housing[pd.Period('2009Q4', 'Q-DEC')]`, depending on how you imported pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your columns to string like this:

```
housing.columns=housing.columns.to_series().astype(str)
```

And then you can access a columns via its str name:

```
housing['2008Q3'].head()

0    499766.666667
1    469500.000000
2    232000.000000
3    116933.333333
4    193766.666667
Name: 2008Q3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Holy Yeaah! Thanks!